# how would I add a twig sub-function or shortcut to translate text

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization, twig, silex

I'm trying now to get a subfunction going.

Now I am using

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
{{ app.translator.trans('keyword')|filters }}
```

To get my i18n translations going, to avoid the usage of hardcoded text, most of the application text runs on yml trans files.

Is there a way to create a "shortcut" of sorts for it?

like

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
{{ tr('keyword')|filters }}
```

or

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
{{ tr.keyword|filters }}
```

Where `tr` is the shortcut for `app.translator.trans` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'trans' when using TwigServiceProvider:

```
 {{ 'keyword'|trans }}
```

http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/translation.html#accessing-translations-in-twig-templates

Comment: oh im sorry but that doesnt work for me, not sure why!

**Variable "repeat_text" does not exist in "admin/staff-edit.html.twig" at line 58**
 the line 58 has **{{ repeat_text|trans }}**
whereas 
**{% trans %}repeat_text{% endtrans %}**
works which is why im looking to make either a new filter or shortcut.

Comment: just for the sake of reference, here is my translator code
    `$app['translator'] = $app->share($app->extend('translator', function($translator, $app) {
    $translator->addLoader('yaml', new YamlFileLoaderTranslation(new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../var/resources/locales')));

    $translator->addResource('yaml', __DIR__.'/../var/resources/locales/en-US.yml', 'en-US');
    $translator->addResource('yaml', __DIR__.'/../var/resources/locales/es-ES.yml', 'es-ES');

    return $translator;
}));`

Comment: Try {{ 'repeat_text'|trans }}

Comment: thanks that did the trick! its time to start modifyingmy `{% trans %}bleh{% endtrans %}` I really thank you!